# Catching my values - they do not come back to where I want them

Tags: c#

Excuse my bad English, it is such that I am dyslexic and has difficulty writing.

This is how I should use some values over on my side where I collect some information when I try it will only download epayId and it will not pick up the other two,

what am I doing wrong since it will only retrieve one of the three?

```
public string HentEpayIdFraPriser(int prisId)
{
    SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
    SqlCommand cmd1 = conn1.CreateCommand();
    cmd1.Connection = conn1;
    cmd1.CommandText = @"SELECT priser, epayId, mdr from Priser WHERE id = @id";
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", prisId);
    conn1.Open();
    SqlDataReader readerBrugerA = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
    var epayId = "0";
    var priser = "0";
    var mdr = "0";
    if (readerBrugerA.Read())
    {

        priser = readerBrugerA["priser"].ToString();
        mdr = readerBrugerA["mdr"].ToString();
        epayId = readerBrugerA["epayId"].ToString();
    }
    conn1.Close();
    return epayId;
}
```

t could be because I do not returer the other two values?

Comment: @l19 its not work. :(

Comment: you are only returning epayId.

Comment: @RaySuelzer Yea, and how i reture priser, mdr and epayid?

Comment: `return` will only return one value. Try creating a class that encapsulates all of the values you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create a Data Transfer Object that you can pass around.  An implementation might look like this.

```
    public class PriserMdrEpayIdDto
    {
        public PriserMdrEpayIdDto(string priser, string mdr, string epayId)
        {
            Priser = priser;
            Mdr = mdr;
            EpayId = EpayId;
        }

        public string Priser { get; set; }
        public string Mdr { get; set; }
        public string EpayId { get; set; }

    }

public PriserMdrEpayIdDto HentEpayIdFraPriser(int prisId)
{
    SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
    SqlCommand cmd1 = conn1.CreateCommand();
    cmd1.Connection = conn1;
    cmd1.CommandText = @"SELECT priser, epayId, mdr from Priser WHERE id = @id";
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", prisId);
    conn1.Open();
    SqlDataReader readerBrugerA = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
    var epayId = "0";
    var priser = "0";
    var mdr = "0";
    if (readerBrugerA.Read())
    {

        priser = readerBrugerA["priser"].ToString();
        mdr = readerBrugerA["mdr"].ToString();
        epayId = readerBrugerA["epayId"].ToString();
        var result = new PriserMdrEpayIdDto(priser, mdr, epayId);
        conn1.Close(); 
        return result;
    }
   return null;
}
```